# Post not working in PHP function, even though var_dump in same function shows the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm befuddled.  I have a JavaScript function that posts to a PHP function.  PHP says, "undefined index" on `mPicker`.  Yet if I call `var_dump` within the same function `mPicker` is plainly visible.

[image: console.log]

I've also ran an alert client side in JavaScript to be sure the form data was serialized, and it too shows that `mPicke`r indeed has a value.  Yet this line in PHP returns the error:

```
$es=$_POST["mPicker"];
```

This is just short hand for all your sake.  The longer version of the code tests for SQL injection.

And the error in xdebug:

[image: php error in xdebug]

The JavaScript code:

```
$.post("./php/adates.php", { atype: apttype, data: $("#apptForm").serialize() })
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

And more of the php function code:

```
if (isset($_POST["atype"]) && !empty($_POST["atype"])) {
    $typ = test_input($_POST['atype'], $con);
} else {
    echo "error ln 6: typ is undefined.";
}

$es=$_POST["mPicker"];
echo $es;
exit;
```

`test_input` is the function I mentioned that tests for SQL injection, and just for testing, have omitted temporarily on the post on `mPicker`.  As you can see, the line `$_POST["atype"]` escapes error, and is perfectly resolved in the PHP function.  I know I am tired and must be missing something stupid.  Help, anyone!

Comment: The first time the page loads, $_POST['mpicker'] won't be set - so you'll get an error or warning.  Test for mPicker the same way you test for atype.

Comment: Seems to me that you are posting exactly two fields, one called `atype` and the other called `data`.

Comment: `!empty` will suffice, `isset` is not needed.

Comment: @nnnnnn and all,  that is partly correct.  Data is a serialized form.  This "page" never loads.  It runs in the background and simply updates the mysql table from the posted data, like several hundred other php functions in my project.  This is the first time I've had one where I thought everything was set up perfectly, then for who knows why, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use jQuery  "ajax" instead of "post"

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html){
     console.log(html)
  }

});
```

and set the dataType to "html", then use "echo" or "var_dunmp" in php, you can see ur data in console

Comment: sorry, "var_dump" not "var_dunmp"

Comment: I had tried ajax with the same result.  But I discovered the problem was the way I was sending two separate variables (one being the serialized form data).  So I added this line before the ajax call:
'var data = "atype="+apttype+"&"+$("#apptForm").serialize();`

Now, it works.  Thanks.